# Android: Softkeyboard next button issue

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an edittext which takes numbers, when I click on it keyboard(numeric) shows up. After puting my values in it I press that next button which then open ups another keyboard(alphabet)which bascially I don't want and now on pressing done this time dismiss the keyboard. I want to skip the alphabet keyboard. I have even tried

```
if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);}
```

Any sugesstion

Comment: Is there another `EditText` after the one with the numeric keyboard?

Comment: yes but focus is false

Comment: Do you need the `Next` button on that keyboard?

Comment: no, I just want the keyboard to be hidden after entering my values

Comment: Then add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to the `EditText`

Comment: Is this in an `Activity` or `Dialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to the `EditText` tag in your XML layout.